# How to get personid from tbl_masseur to personid in tbl_sched

Tags: php, mysql

[tbl_sched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njxjG.png)

[tbl_masseur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYGml.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQoH.png)

I want to display my personid firstname date_start date_end time_start time_end
but the problem is i cannot display my personid and firstname.

Comment: that is called a **Join** in SQL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For clarification I would like to ask on how can i can get data from the personid in the tbl_masseur and copy the personid to the tbl_sched. And how can i display it as a table where it shows id, firstname, last name alongside with the  date_start, date_end time_start, time_end

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution :

To select what data to display

```
SELECT tbl_masseur.personid, tbl_masseur.firstname, tbl_masseur.lastname, tbl_sched.date_start, tbl_sched.date_end, tbl_sched.time_start, tbl_sched.time_end 

FROM tbl_masseur

JOIN tbl_sched

ON tbl_masseur.personid = tbl_sched.personid
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).